# How to add a chart with a table in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, chart.js

I am using Chart JS 2.5 to visualize 2 data objects in bar charts and I can visualize the data values from both objects but I would like to see a table that also shows the data below these two graphs.

[image: ChartJS2.5]

```
Table view that I would like to have
Date      Data Object 1      Data Object 2
2 Jan     6                  16
9 Jan     87                 57
16 Jan    56                 23
23 Jan    15                 60
30 Jan    88                 78
6 Feb     60                 40
13 Feb    12                 42
```

This is the code I currently have for generating the graphs.

**How do I retrieve the data**

**Django - code snippet for the data retrieval from the internal web API**

```
class ChartData(APIView):

def get(self,request, format=None):
....
# get the filtered json per engineer for the current week
    weeks_of_data = []
    for index, value in enumerate(list_of_engineers): 
        week_of_data.append(filter_url(list_of_engineers[index]).json())       

def filter_url(engineer):
    filters = {"filter": {
        "filters": [{
            "field": "Triage_DateTime",
            "operator": "gte",
            "value": "2017-07-16 23:59:59"
        }, {
            "field": "Triage_DateTime",
            "operator": "lte",
            "value": "2017-08-11 23:59:59"
        }, {
            "field": "Triage_Subcategory",
            "operator": "neq",
            "value": "Temporary Degradation"
        }, {
            "field": "Triage_Engineer",
            "operator": "eq",
            "value": str(engineer)
        }],
        "logic": "and"
    }}
url = "http://10.61.202.98:8081/T/ansdb/api/rows/dev/t/tickets?"
response = requests.post(url, json=filters)
return response
```

**Raw JS script to display the graphs**

```
<script>
    {% block jquery %}
    var endpoint = '/statistics/chart-data' //This works with the chart_data view.
    var data_of_weeks = []
    var label_number_weeks = []

$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: endpoint,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data)
        label_number_weeks = data.label_number_weeks
        data_of_weeks = data.data_of_weeks
        setChart()

    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error on data")
        console.log(error_data)
    }
})

function setChart()
{
var ctx_tickets       = document.getElementById("tickets")

var tickets = new Chart(ctx_tickets, {

    type:'bar',
    data: {
        labels: label_number_weeks,
        datasets :
            [
            {
                label: 'Week 29',
                data: [data_of_weeks[3], data_of_weeks[7],data_of_weeks[11],data_of_weeks[15],data_of_weeks[19],
                       data_of_weeks[23],data_of_weeks[27],data_of_weeks[31],data_of_weeks[35]],
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
                borderColor: '#777',
                borderWidth: 1,
                hoverBorderWidth: 3,
                hoverBorderColor: '#000'
            },
        ]},
        options: {
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
          },

          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Tickets by engineer per week',
            fontSize: 30
            },
        legend: {
            position: 'right',
            display: true,
            labels: {
                fontColor: '#000'
                }
            },
            layout: {
                padding: {
                    left: 50,
                    right: 0,
                    bottom: 0,
                    top: 0
                    }
            },
            tooltips: {
              enabled: true
            },

          hover : {
            animationDuration: 0
          },

          animation: {
            duration: 0.8,
            onComplete: function(){
                var chartInstance = this.chart,
                ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
                ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

                this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                var isHidden = dataset._meta[0].hidden; //'hidden' property of dataset
                if (!isHidden) { //if dataset is not hidden
                    var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                    meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                        var data = dataset.data[index];
                        ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);});
                    }});
            }
          }
        }
    })
}

{% endblock %}
</script>
```

**simplified HTML for testing purposes**

```
<canvas>id="myChart" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

**simplified JS script for testing purposes**

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
debugger;
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
data: {
    labels: ["2 Jan", "9 Jan", "16 Jan", "23 Jan", "30 Jan", "6 Feb", "13 Feb"],
datasets: [{
    label: 'Data object 1',
    data: [6, 87, 56, 15, 88, 60, 12],
    fill: false,
    backgroundColor: "#4082c4",
},

{
    label: 'Data object 2',
    data: [16, 57, 23, 60, 88, 40, 42],
    fill: false,
    backgroundColor: "#9082d4",
}]
},
 options: {
    "hover": {
    "animationDuration": 1
},
"animation": {
    "duration": 1,
                "onComplete": function () {
                    var chartInstance = this.chart,
                        ctx = chartInstance.ctx;

                    ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                    ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

                    this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                    var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                    meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                    var data = dataset.data[index];                            
                    ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);
                });
            });
        }
    },

legend:{
    "display": true
   },
tooltips: {
    "enabled": true
 },
scales: {
    yAxes: [{
            display: false,
            gridLines: {
            display : false
        },
        ticks: {
                display: false,
            beginAtZero:true
            }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                display : false
            },
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
            }
        }]
    }
}
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.2/Chart.js"</script>
```

**JS Fiddle**
[Edit online](https://jsfiddle.net/alex9007/4mxhogmd/14/)

Is it possible to add a table below these two graphs with ChartJS? 
Will it be preferrable to use another tool such as highCharts or Chartist.js or Dygraphs? I am not using huge amounts of data to graph, so this is the main reason I decided to use Chart.js.

Comment: sounds like you can just make a styled `<table>` and plug in the data and skip the extension

Comment: How can I make this?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Answer (score 2):

If you not using php to generate this charts, you need to do that manula, just do table in html and put values there. If you got database for this you can read from DB and put to table, normal php function SELECT. You put this value to charts manual ?

Comment: I am using Django to get the data from a Web API. I do not want to use a manual table .

Comment: show me results of requested API, how you get this values to charts?

Comment: Please, see the updated code from the original question.

Comment: ok thats make this charts, but from where you get values ? for example: ata: [6, 87, 56, 15, 88, 60, 12],

Comment: Those values are retrieved from `data: [data_of_weeks[3], data_of_weeks[7],data_of_weeks[11],...[]]` which comes from `data_of_weeks = data.data_of_weeks` which comes from `Chart Data` which comes from the web API at internal address http://10.61.202.98:8081/T/ansdb/api/rows/dev/t/tickets?

Comment: so put this values to table in foreach loope to retrive data from array.
$datas = data_of_weeks
$datachart = array();
foreach ($datas as $data) {
$datachart[] =  $data
} <--- something like that.